# Alias URL not changing when switching language in a View

Tags: path-aliases

I have a content node in 2 languages. When I use the language switcher while displaying the English content:

www.example.com/en/content/Article-on-relativity

it displays correctly the translated content in Spanish in this URL

www.example.com/es/content/Articulo-sobre-relatividad

However, when I include the contents filtered in a View, the language switcher only swiths the first part of the URL, but not the alias URL of the content itself, displaying Not Found

www.example.com/en/myView/Article-on-relativity

changes to

www.example.com/es/miVista/Article-on-relativity

instead of the desired

www.example.com/es/miVista/Articulo-sobre-relatividad

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use [i18n_page_views](http://drupal.org/project/i18n_page_views) module - it is a display plugin that installs an item labeled `i18n page` into the **+Add** (display) button menu. It's like a `page` display extended by fields for entering a path for each enabled language.

While it does not offer any tool to convert existing displays into i18_page type, it's quite easy to do that manually - just export your existing view(s), change the type of the display in a notepad and re-import w/override.

Regretfully, the module does not offer UI for creating translated menu items - this also has to be done manually.

At any rate, it's advisable to bind all translation paths (created manually as jdu suggested, or created automatically) into a translation path set (`admin/config/regional/i18n_translation/path/add`). I found that without it the `i18n_get_path_translations` function worked whimsically.

Comment: I had to do this finally: foreach($links as $lang => $url_arr){
   $content_arr = explode("/", $url_arr["href"]);
   $content = $content_arr[2];
   $node_id = drupal_lookup_path('source', 'content/' . $content);
   $translations = translation_path_get_translations($node_id);
   $translation = drupal_get_path_alias($translations[$lang], $lang);
   $translation_arr = explode("/", $translation);
   $string = "";
   
   for($i=0;$i<count($content_arr)-1;$i++){
    $string .= $content_arr[$i] . "/";
   } // for
   
   $string .= $translation_arr[1];
   $links[$lang]["href"] = $string;
  }